# Levenshtein Distance with Python to compare words

Tags: python, excel, levenshtein-distance

I have a dataset with the column "names" and I duplicate that dataset and made a few mistakes. For example I have "Adidas" and I made "Addas".

i want that if I read the fake dataset that the code change from "Addas" to "Adidas"

But there can be some problems because if I have two similar words like "XY Company" and "XY Company Co." and I read in my fake dataset the word "XY C0mpany", than It would be nice if that change to "XY Company".

So for that I am using the method

```
nltk.edit_distance()
```

What are the better way if I read all the column "names" from both datasets with

```
pd.read_excel()
```

and than compare that each other. But how I can change the wrong word ?
That give me only a accuracy

Comment: How would your code know "Adidas" is correct and "Addas" isn't?

Comment: Based on the frequencies